# Why is PyCharm giving me an Unresolved Reference NameError

Tags: python, scripting

I'm taking a tutorial to learn Python.  I've written the code you see below:

```
creatures = []

def get_creature_race():
    creature_race = []
    for creature in creatures:
        creature_race.append(creature["race"].title())
    return creature_race


def print_creature_race():
    creature_race = get_creature_race()
    print(creature_race)


def add_creature(race, sex):
    creature = {"race": race, "creature_sex": sex}
    creatures.append(creature)


def save_file(creature):
    try:
        f = open("creatures.txt", "a")
        f.write(creature + "\n")
        f.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Could not save file")


def read_file():
    f = open("creatures.txt", "r")
    for creature in f.readlines():
        add_creature(creature)
    f.close()


read_file()
print_creature_race()


creature_race = input("Enter creature race: ")
creature_sex = input("Enter creature sex: ")

add_creature(creature_race, creature_sex)
print_creature_race()
save_file(creature_race)
```

When I try to run this I get the following:

```
...line 32, in read_file
    add_creature(creature)
TypeError: add_creature() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sex'
```

Line 32 is the 4th line in the read_file() function definition:

```
add_creature(creature)
```

If I hover over the right most parenthesis ')' I get:

```
Parameter 'sex' unfilled
```

If I put the second parameter in:

```
def read_file():
    f = open("creatures.txt", "r")
    for creature in f.readlines():
        add_creature(creature, sex)
    f.close()
    print("Could not read file")
```

I get:

```
line 32, in read_file
    add_creature(creature, sex)
NameError: name 'sex' is not defined
```

When I hover over sex it gives me:

```
Unresolved reference sex
```

If I put a try block around def read_file() so I can run the program without it erroring out:

```
def read_file():
    try:
        f = open("creatures.txt", "r")
        for creature in f.readlines():
            add_creature(creature, sex)
        f.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Could not read file")
```

and run it I get the following:

```
Could not read file
[]
Enter creature race: giant
Enter creature sex: male
['Giant']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The first line is the exception from the read_file() function because creatures.txt doesn't exist yet (or so I thought).  The [] is the output from print_creature_race() function since it is currently empty.  The next two "Enter..." statements should be self-explanatory.  ['Giant'] is the output from the second print_creature_race() function call.  I now have a creatures.txt file with the word 'giant' in it.

Now, according to the tutorial, if I run this a second time what I should get is:

```
giant

Enter creature race: elf
Enter creature sex: female
```

There's no exception because the file creatures.txt now exists.  The print_creature_race() function call results in 'giant' being printed.  And I get the two prompts to enter another race and sex.  HOWEVER, what I actually get is:

```
Could not read file
[]
Enter creature race:
```

If I continue with the prompts I get:

```
Could not read file
[]
Enter creature race: elf
Enter creature sex: female
['Elf']
```

My creatures.txt file has giant and elf (each on its own line) but, obviously, I still can't read the file.  The definition for add_creature has two parameters but I get an error both for including it and not including it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either there is something wrong with the tutorial you are following, or you did not understand something. You cannot use `add_creature` without also having the sex of the creature. If the file only contains the possible species then you probably should not add the to the creature list. Moreover, without telling us which tutorial it is we cannot say whether you are wrong or the tutorial is simply broken.

Comment: You may need to write the `creature_sex` in the file next to the `creature` separated by a space, and parse each line when you read the file (with `line.split()`). Don't forget to add the new parameter in every function : save_file... and when you call them too

Comment: Bakuriu, obviously I don't understand something.  That's why I'm asking the question.  I do understand how function calls work from working with other languages which is why I don't get why the tutorial calls the function with only one parameter.  I don't understand Python so I'm asking hoping someone can explain the 'why' to me.  Not sure why a negative vote is necessary for simply asking a question.  Even if it wasn't you...

Answer (score 0):

Please learn how to debug your code!
I'll just give some hints. These, however, will not lead to succes (as  Paul Cornelius pointed out)

fix last line:

`save_file(creature_race)`

to

`save_file(creatures)`

Brief explanation:
you are saving only the race, while your functions await both: race and sex.

You should also review hot to appropriatelly save your data in a file and read it. (check for python+csv for example).

Also: the functions you created are bad - they are not encapsulated. Try to rethink the code in a way, that none of your functions have to call or change external variables. Then you can start your code, without executing any of the functions, and call them one by one to see what they do. Watch at your global variables changing and fix the code on the go.

Comment: This will not help, since the resulting file will contain neither creature names nor sexes but the default formatting of a python list named `creatures`.  The tutorial seems not to explain how to write the file or parse it in a way that will allow the script to work.  Perhaps OP can tell us where the tutorial comes from.

Comment: true.... did not pay attention to it. Actually, I would not reccomend working with files right away, before understanding how other stuff work. All the programming pinciples, like DRY, encapsulation, and what a good algorithm is.

Comment: save_file(creature_race) is correct.  I double checked the tutorial to make sure.  I also get an error when I try your suggestion.  The tutorial I'm taking is Python: Getting Started by Bo Milanovich on Pluralsight.  It's in the fouth module under Opening, Reading, and Writing...  Here is the link: [link](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=python-getting-started&author=bo-milanovich&name=python-getting-started-m3&clip=6&mode=live)

Comment: unfortunatelly I cannot open the link. I'll try to provide you some usefull tutorials tomorrow. (need some sleep now).

Comment: These here are good starting points:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

http://python-history.blogspot.de/2009/01/pythons-design-philosophy.html

www.pythonforbeginners.com/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Then you should watch some youtube videos on debugging in PyCharm (best thing ever).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I missed a minor detail in the code.  In the add_creature() definition I had to assign a default value to sex:

```
def add_creature(race, sex="male"):
    creature = {"race": race, "creature_sex": sex}
    creatures.append(creature)
```

This is how the tutorial was able to call the function with only the race parameter.  Once I added `="male"` the code works as expected.